How do I Inject Dependencies in FastAPI's Lifespan Context / startup event?
I'm developing a backend service using FastAPI, and I'm facing issues with dependency injection when trying to perform data processing during the application's startup.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
I have a Repository class that depends on a MongoDB database instance, injected like this:
class Repository:
    def __init__(self, db: Database):
        self.collection = db['my_collection']
        # other initialization

def init_my_repository(db=Depends(get_mongo_database_instance)):
    return Repository(db)

In my application, I need to perform some initialization tasks using this repository (and other services) when the FastAPI app starts. My first thought was to do this in the lifespan context:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI, 
                   repo=Depends(init_my_repository), 
                   xxx=Depends(init_my_XXX), 
                   yyy=Depends(init_my_YYY)):
    repo.do_something()
    xxx.do_something()
    yyy.do_something()
    yield

However, this approach doesn't work as expected because Depends can't be used directly within the lifespan context.
This limitation forces me to manually create instances of these dependencies, which defeats the purpose of using FastAPI's automatic dependency injection....!!
I found a discussion here that offers a workaround, but it doesn't work in my codebase.
Given how common this scenario is in other IoC-based frameworks, I'm surprised there isn't a straightforward solution in FastAPI.
Please help. Thanks!

Call get_mongo_database_instance directly: get_mongo_database_instance() - there is nothing more magical going on there when you don't need to resolve a dependency hiearchy or cache the dependency between other dependencies. Depends is intended to resolve dependencies dynamically for a given request - i.e. where things depend on the request itself.

@MatsLindh Thanks. But what if I need to resolve a complex dependency hierarchy (sub-dependencies, sub-sub-dependencies...) ? If I have to manually create these dependencies instead of relying on IoC to handle them, it feels incredibly inefficient and counterproductive. Or am I missing something here?

Dependencies as declared in endpoints should not be confused with a generic dependency injection framework. Depends() will just only work for FastAPI endpoints. Nothing really you can do but to refactor your code.

@JarroVGIT Thank you. It's a clear point. Then based on your point, would you recommend using a standalone generic dependency injection framework and integrating it into FastAPI's lifecycle?
